# Promises stop looping when XMLHttpRequest Internet is off

Tags: javascript, promise, xmlhttprequest

I have some code which loops 2 methods.

Method 2 checks a URL using `XMLHttpRequest`.

The problem I'm having is that when there Internet is active it continues to loop but as soon as I turn the Internet off XMLHttpRequest will fail and stop looping.

Here is the code:

```
    one() {
        return new Promise(resolve=> {
            // Does something and returns either true or false
        })

    }

    two() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            const httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            httpRequest.open("GET", 'someurl', true);
            httpRequest.send();
            httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    resolve(this);
                }
            };
        })
    }

    loop() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.one()
                .then(()=>this.two().then(response => {
                    if (response.status === 200) {
                        // Its True
                    } else {
                        // Its False
                    }
                }))
                .then(()=>this.loop())
        }, 5000);
    }

}
```

How can I make it so it continues looping no matter what?

Comment: change your `if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)` to `if (true)` I guess

Comment: Think about it, if the internet it off, the XMLHTTPRequest is not going to be successful. So than you would need to reject the promise for the error.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add onerror handler

```
       httpRequest.onerror = function() {
           resolve({ error: true });
       };
```

Also you may want to throw and catch an error

```
two() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) {
       // ...
       httpRequest.onerror = function() {
           reject();
       };
    });
}

loop() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.one()
            .then(()=>this.two()
            // ...
            .then(() => this.loop())
            .catch(() => this.loop())
    }, 5000);
}
```

The second approach allows you to interrupt the promise chain immediately, it could be helpful in case you have `three`, `four` etc methods.